# Table name after parenthesis notation

Tags: sql

I was going through some old-ish SQL code someone else had written that I couldn't quite understand. I have simplified its structure here, but if anyone can walk me through what exactly is going on, that would be appreciated! You may ignore the specific column operations as they were just examples.

```
SELECT table.*,
  column1 - column2
  AS 'col1 - col2',

 ...

  columnn
  AS 'coln'

FROM
  (SELECT

  ...

  ) table
```

What I don't understand is the final line. I am assuming it is the definition of "table" in the `FROM (SELECT ...)` part, and the `) table` part indicates the name of the defined table.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The `table` at the end is a very very very (etc) bad alias for the derived table (the select inside parens)

Comment: It's an alias.  Since this is a sub-query, it is required to give the resultset an alias.  This is just how it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An inner select needs an alias name

```
select alias_name.* from
(
   select * from some_table ...
) alias_name
```

Answer (score 1):

The 'table' in that final line is an alias for the subquery.

In T-SQL it is AFAIK mandatory to specify an alias for a subquery if you're selecting from a subquery.
You can name the alias whathever you want.   It is perfectly ok to use it like this

```
select * from
   ( select * from ... ) as X
```

(The as keyword is not mandatory, but I always specify the alias-name using 'as').